# Joomla Translation Extension - The simplest way

Tags: joomla, translation

Can anyone point out an extension where we can add articles in another language, the point is to allow the user to create an article similar to the ones already existent and write them in another language, so that, when the users clicks the flag of that language, the articles (and menu) will switch to those is English.

According to joomla documentation I can answer this questions like so:

Is the site structure of all languages the same or do I have different "views"?
 - The same;

Do I need language related content such as different products in a shop?
 - No.

Are regions/countries related to languages or is the new language primarily a translation?
 - related;

Do I have different authors, publishers and so on for my various languages?
 - No.

Do I need a professional translation for my site or is an automated translation (e.g. by Google) acceptable?
 - No.

I have found only extensions that deal with automatic translations or with locale files and stuff like that, and the intended is something really simple, without any of those stuff.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Joomfish to create fully manageable multilingual website using Joomla

The problem with Joomfish is it's not compatible with Joomla 1.7

If you wanted to create multilingual website using Joomla 1.7 you should [check this article](http://www.webeks.net/joomla/multilingual-joomla-17.html)

Comment: Yep, moreover since J1.7 for each menu item we can set-up "Menu Item Assocations" so that, when viewing an article clicking on a flag in order to change site's language the site will be redirected to the same article in other language. That's why Joomfish is not supported in J1.7, simply is not needed any more